# Can I migrate a tor hiddenservice from one user/PC to another?

Tags: sync, tor, configuration-management

Is there a way to migrate the hidden service from one PC to another?

I have tried to put hiddenservice folder with host and private key in another tor, but got this error:

```
Dec 24 00:11:38.793 [warn] /home/bibi/.hidden_service1/ is not owned by this user (debian-tor, 115) but by bibi (1000). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?
Dec 24 00:11:38.793 [warn] Error loading rendezvous service keys
Dec 24 00:11:38.794 [err] set_options(): Bug: Acting on config options left us in a broken state. Dying.
```

Comment: belongs on ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

All information about Tor Hidden Services are inside the directory `/var/lib/tor` (assuming Tor is installing as Ubuntu package). So you should do the following steps to migrate your hidden service.

1. Open a terminal.
2. Stop your Tor service: `sudo service tor stop`
   This step is not necessary. It is just a cautionary measure.
3. Inside the directory `/var/lib/tor` is a subdirectory `hidden_service`. If this is not the case, have a look into your `/etc/tor/torrc`. There is a variable called `HiddenServiceDir`. This tells you the actual location of the subdirectory. I will assume that the correct directory is `/var/lib/tor/hidden_service`.
4. Make a backup of the files

   1. `/etc/tor/torrc`
   2. `/var/lib/tor/hidden_service/private_key` and `/var/lib/tor/hidden_service/hostname`
5. Change to the other machine and stop the Tor service there.
6. Create a hidden service directory on your new machine: `sudo -u debian-tor mkdir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service` and change permissions: `sudo -u debian-tor chmod 2700 /var/lib/tor/hidden_service`.
7. Copy the `private_key` and `hostname` to the new directory and make sure that only the user `debian-tor` can read and write both files.
8. Edit your `/etc/tor/torrc`. You should at least set `HiddenServiceDir` and `HiddenServicePort`. Another possibility is to use your backup. You can just copy it to `/etc/tor`.
9. Start the Tor service.

Now you are finished migrating the hidden service and it is reachable again.